# Flexible street script/tool?

Tags: scripting

I'm new to blender Blender and mainly use POV-Ray. Would it be possible in Blender to create scripts or custom tools that generate flexible roads? Like this:

http://lib.povray.org/searchcollection/index2.php?objectName=LegoRoad&contributorTag=SharkD

Except (preferably) modifiable in real time by dragging control points using the mouse?

Thanks!

Comment: Please revise your question to a single issue. If you have multiple questions, please post them individually.

Comment: Okay I did that. Is it better?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7553/create-a-road-along-large-terrain and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14818/how-can-i-texture-a-complex-road-system/14834#14834

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using curves you should be able to do something similar.

[image]

On top view add a curve, give it some extrusion and depth. Enter edit mode and align the control points by pressing <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.
Exit edit mode and rotate the curve 90 degrees on the x axis (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>) Go back to edit mode and manipulate your curve by adding points (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>RMB</kbd> and manipulating them you can get any shape you want.

Comment: I need to texture the object. How do I make the texture follow the curve?

Comment: @posfan12 please ask a new question on this instead.