# How to uv wrap a curve

Tags: uv, bezier-curves

I have made a curve road and i want to unwrap the texture. Can we uv wrap texture to curve. If yes then why there is no option for uv wrap. If no then how can i wrap road texture to the curve.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Convert to mesh then unwrap

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yes but if i want my curve to be texture then. Why the option is there in material image texture it means we can texture the curve also.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14818/how-can-i-texture-a-complex-road-system/14834#14834

Comment: You need to press Alt+c to convert it to mesh. But I opened the .blend and unfortunately, I don't think you will be able to map the road texture on this untidy mesh topology so it would look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the Curve to Mesh (Alt+c)

Go to top view uv wrap and press u and select project from view

select one of the road and uv wrap the image of the road

After uvwrap on one of the road press u and with the Magic UV addon press U and select the copy/paste -> Copy uv -> default

The select all press A to select all Faces and deselect the face which is uvwrap and then Press U
copy/paste -> Paste uv -> default

And u have all the texture on the mesh. More than 95% it work well few issue we can set manually

[image]